# Use AdBlock without being detected

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, adblock

Upon visiting a site today I was rewarded with Comic Sans.

Behold it's glory:

[image]
**[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson1/)**

Needless to say I can finally understand why so many people loathe this font.

However, this does bring up a question.

Will websites ever become smart enough to simply stop displaying content to AdBlock users altogether? If so, then what can be done about it?

I understand that this is probably just some small JS checker embedded in the HTML so AdBlock cannot block the detection of it's own anti-ad antics but I found this "reward" to be quite funny.

Comment: heh, thats an interesting response to adblocking. No, it would not be easy to prevent client side scripts from detecting Adblock, as it removes elements from the DOM, which the scripts can evaluate, to determine if you have loaded the ad panels or not. Websites are already "smart enough" to provide bogus output if they like, unless you disable client side scripting like javascript. NoScript, Ghostery, and RequestPolicy are just a few examples of how you might be more selective in the scripts that run, but then the provider willj just bundle them with required functionality so you need them.

Comment: Are you using AdBlock or AdBlock Plus? I'm using the latter and don't get any warning nor ugly font when visiting the link you provided.

Comment: What does a question about `Comic Sans` have to do with AdBlock?

Comment: @Ramhound, from the banner, the site operators are applying a ComicSans font to any render where an adblocker is in play.

Comment: They are not catching use of [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) "" either ;)

Comment: What browser and ad-blocking extension are you using? On Firefox with uBlock Origin and Fanboy Ultimate List, the ad blocking is not detected by the website.

Comment: @galacticninja Web browser is defined in the tags of the question. [AdBlock v2.39](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Try uBlock Origin instead of AdBlock.

Comment: What did you try to resolve the issue? Did uBlock Origin or AdBlock Plus work?

Comment: BTW, you can force a font in firefox. I don't know for other browsers.

Comment: Much rather look at Comic Sans than ads. Honestly, it doesn't look that bad. I mean.. it could be way way worse with like WingDings or some such.

Comment: If you disable javascript for the site you will not get ads or adblock detection. Most blogs and news sites will work fine, but it may interfere with other sites. On the other hand, sites that disabling javascript interferes with usually don't care if you use adblockers because they are marketing something actually useful and don't need to use ads to beg for clickbait revenue.

Answer (score 20):

Change your ad blocking extension to [**uBlock Origin**](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) ([Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) / [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)). The page appears normally and without ads in uBlock Origin in both Firefox and Chrome.

In settings » Filter Lists, enable all the filters in the Built-in, Ads, Privacy, Malware Domains, and Multipurpose sections.

Comment: There is also an optional anti-adblock killer from Reek. I recommend this as well.

Comment: uBlock can be also detected for example on this site: http://www.mindgames.com/game/Rapid+Math

Comment: @fodma1 Looks like a filter list issue. Try reporting it to the EasyList maintainers: https://forums.lanik.us/index.php

Comment: Also available for Safari: https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.el1t.uBlock-3NU33NW2M3 Repo: https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari#ublock-originfor-safari

Comment: Would like to add here that Anti-Adblock Killer by reek has been abandoned and discontinued since November 2016. It has been superseded by Nano Defender.

Answer (score 14):

I've been able to successfully stop detection of AdBlock on various sites by following their instructions to [enable content when AdBlock is detected](http://support.getadblock.com/kb/other-problems/a-website-isnt-letting-me-access-its-contents-when-adblock-is-enabled). The instructions basically require you to add the [AakList](http://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/#fiterlist) (Anti-AdBlock Killer filter list) to the AdBlock filter lists, and also create a custom filter for the sites that are blocking content because of AdBlock. The filter's format is `@@||example.com$elemhide` (instructions tested & correct as of the November 2015 version)

**EDIT** AakList has added simpler instructions to add their list for most modern browsers, follow **[this link](https://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/#filterlist)**, click on "Subscribe", and that's it (I tested on Firefox)

Comment: elemhide worked! that list is actually [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reek/anti-adblock-killer/master/anti-adblock-killer-filters.txt)

Comment: Would like to add here that the Anti-Adblock Killer (AAK) by reek has been abandoned and discontinued since November 2016. It has been superseded by Nano Defender.

Answer (score 7):

You can add an adblock detection removal list where you add your other filters.

1. Go to your ad blocker's settings.
2. If available just activate an adblock warning removal filter.
3. If there's no such filter available, go to custom or my filters, and add one of the ad block warning filter URLs. See below.

#### Ad Block warning filters

- [EasyList Adblock Warning Removal List](https://easylist.adblockplus.org)
- [Anti AdBlockKiller](http://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/)

### uBlock

[image]

### AdBlock Plus in Chrome

[image: AdBlock Plus in Chrome]

Comment: Anti-Adblock Killer (AAK) by reek has been abandoned and discontinued since November 2016. It has been superseded by Nano Defender.

Answer (score 1):

Download ghostery extensions/addon depeding on your browser. Then restrict the site from seeing information about you. The site will work after.

Comment: @fixer1234 After seeing your comment, I did a lot of digging. I was previously under the impression that Better Advertising, the company that bought the Ghostery extension (they have since changed their name first to Evidon and then Ghostery), had another product that was actually adware (the unwanted program kind that produces extra pop-ups, etc.). However, I was unable to uncover anything about the other product that I remembered. I have nothing in particular against GhostRank - I use Adblock Plus myself (though with Acceptable Ads disabled). Thanks for your comment, I deleted my original.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone but I needed Fanboy's Annoyance List to block ads on Seattle times. Here is my full list of adblock filters. These filters can be found here.

https://easylist.to/

[image]